# efficiently break Kotlin string into fixed length sub-strings without using regex

Tags: kotlin

obviously to split can be used to break a string in to sub-strings at specific character or delimiter string, but i was looking for any easy way to break into fixed length sub-strings.
eg.

```
"abcde".splitAt(2) == listOf("ab", "cd", "e")
```

any ideas?

Comment: [`String.chunked`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/chunked.html) looks like what you're looking for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`CharSequence.chunked(size: Int)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/chunked.html) function. It does exactly that:

```kotlin
println("abcde".chunked(2)) // [ab, cd, e]
```